# How to restructure an array from the array itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

My array is:

[image: SOURCE ARRAY]

```
[{
        "Id": 1891,
        "AirportCode": "DUB",
        "AirportName": "Dublin Airport",
        "AirportCity": "Dublin",
        "Priority": 1,
        "SubPriority": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 1921,
        "AirportCode": "DXB",
        "AirportName": "Dubai International Airport",
        "AirportCity": "Dubai",
        "Priority": 1,
        "SubPriority": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 1680,
        "AirportCode": "DBN",
        "AirportName": "Dublin Municipal Airport",
        "AirportCity": "Dublin",
        "Priority": 2,
        "SubPriority": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 8973,
        "AirportCode": "XNB",
        "AirportName": "United Arab Emirates - Bus Station",
        "AirportCity": "Dubai",
        "Priority": 2,
        "SubPriority": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 6062,
        "AirportCode": "PSK",
        "AirportName": "New River Valley Airport",
        "AirportCity": "Dublin",
        "Priority": 3,
        "SubPriority": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 1681,
        "AirportCode": "DBO",
        "AirportName": "Dubbo Airport",
        "AirportCity": "Dubbo",
        "Priority": 99,
        "SubPriority": null
    }
]
```

I want it to be like -

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

I wrote the function as below weher AirportCity is same and SubPriority not null

```
const customAirports = [];
        myArray.map((val, i, arr) => {
            let pushedInSubAirport = false;
            for (let v of customAirports) {
                if (v.AirportCity === (val.SubPriority ?
                    val.AirportCity : undefined)
                ) {
                    if (!v['SubAirport'])
                        Object.assign(v, { SubAirport: [] })
                    v['SubAirport'].push(val);
                    pushedInSubAirport = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!pushedInSubAirport)
                customAirports.push(val)
        });
        myArray = customAirports;
```

If it is not proper please suggest me the solution.

Comment: What are the rules of transformation - in plain terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pay attention on data consistency, e.g. `null`/`0`.

`.map` return another array, in case when it should not, better to use `.forEach`

Avoid modify structures while iterate over it.

```js
const data = [{
  "Id": 1891,
  "AirportCode": "DUB",
  "AirportName": "Dublin Airport",
  "AirportCity": "Dublin",
  "Priority": 1,
  "SubPriority": 0
}, {
  "Id": 1921,
  "AirportCode": "DXB",
  "AirportName": "Dubai International Airport",
  "AirportCity": "Dubai",
  "Priority": 1,
  "SubPriority": 0
}, {
  "Id": 1680,
  "AirportCode": "DBN",
  "AirportName": "Dublin Municipal Airport",
  "AirportCity": "Dublin",
  "Priority": 2,
  "SubPriority": 1
}, {
  "Id": 8973,
  "AirportCode": "XNB",
  "AirportName": "United Arab Emirates - Bus Station",
  "AirportCity": "Dubai",
  "Priority": 2,
  "SubPriority": 1
}, {
  "Id": 6062,
  "AirportCode": "PSK",
  "AirportName": "New River Valley Airport",
  "AirportCity": "Dublin",
  "Priority": 3,
  "SubPriority": 1
}, {
  "Id": 1681,
  "AirportCode": "DBO",
  "AirportName": "Dubbo Airport",
  "AirportCity": "Dubbo",
  "Priority": 99,
  "SubPriority": 0 // null - Inconsistent !!!
}];
const grouped = group(data);

window.result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(grouped, null, 2);

function group(data){
  const [main, subs] = data.reduce(([main, subs], item) => {
    if (item.SubPriority === 0) {
      return [main.concat(item), subs];
    }
    const subList = subs.get(item.AirportCity) || [];
    subs.set(item.AirportCity, subList.concat(item));

    return [main, subs];
  }, [[], new Map()]);

  return main.map((item) => Object.assign(item, {SubAirport: subs.get(item.AirportCity) || []}));
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
this.airports.sort((a,b)=>a.Priority-b.Priority) //sort by priority
    this.airports.forEach((x,index)=>{
      const airport=this.airports.find( //try find one more on top
          (a,index2)=>a.AirportCity==x.AirportCity && index>index2)
      if (airport) //if exist
      {
        if (!airport.SubAirport) //if has not SubAirport
            airport.SubAirport=[{...x}]  //create an array with one element
        else
          airport.SubAirport.push({...x}) //add to array

        x.remove=true; //mark as "removable"
      }

    })
    this.airports=this.airports.filter(x=>!x.remove) //<--remove the removable
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfbysf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: why `[{...x}]`, instead `[x]` and `push(x)`?

Comment: Nesting iteration ` this.airports.forEach` and `airport=this.airports.find` inside may  be not so well solution.

Comment: @Kyr, the spread operator is for avoid add the propertie "remove" (is like your ObjectAsign) in the airports added. About the find I don't see any problem

Comment: aha, I see, spread `x` make sense due to `x` mutated with `.remove` . Using `.find` over array inside iterate over same array is not a problem, it's just O(n2).